# Set extraEnvs ingress variable

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to use `extraEnv` property in order to add additional environment variables to set in the pod using helm charts.

I have a `values.yaml` file that includes:

```
controller:
  service:
      loadBalancerIP:
  extraEnvs:
     - name: ev1
       value: 
     - name: ev2
       value
```

first I've set the loadBalancerIP the following way:

`helm template path/charts/ingress --set nginx-ingress.controller.service.loadBalancerIP=1.1.1.1 --output-dir .`

In order to set `extraEnvs` values I've tried to use the same logic by doing:

`helm template path/charts/ingress --set nginx-ingress.controller.service.loadBalancerIP=1.1.1.1 --set nginx-ingress.controller.extraEnvs[0].value=valueEnv1--set nginx.controller.extraEnvs[1].value=valueEnv2--output-dir .`

But it doesn't work. I looked for the right way to set those variables but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I see you are brand new, so welcome to Stack Overflow!  The syntax in your yaml file is missing the colon for the 2nd `value:` field.   Hopefully, someone will have an answer for you.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 3):

Helm `--set` has some [limitations](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set).

Your best option is to avoid using the `--set`, and use the `--values` flag with your `values.yaml` file instead:

```
helm template path/charts/ingress \
--values=values.yaml
```

---

If you want to use `--set` anyway, the equivalent command should have this notation:

```
helm template path/charts/ingress \
--set=controller.service.loadBalancerIP=1.1.1.1 \
--set=controller.extraEnvs[0].name=ev1,controller.extraEnvs[0].value=valueEnv1 \
--set=controller.extraEnvs[1].name=ev2,controller.extraEnvs[1].value=valueEnv2 \
--output-dir .
```